# MVC - override validation when one particular button is clicked

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table that lists items. I have a form tag that surrounds this table. In this table I have ADD buttons that adds new rows to the database. I have EDIT buttons that edits a row as well. The form posts to the same action on the controller.

Now I need to add a filter row on the first  which means I need to add a Filter button to submit the form with the filter parameters. Since this is still inside the main form, I now have the following problem: When I click the Filter button, the inputs that are used for the ADD button are being validated before anything gets posted. How can I prevent the validation from occurring when the user clicks the Filter button?

Comment: Can you show us some code / html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Filter button is of type "button" not "submit" and do filter using ajax

Answer (score 0):

As i see it, the easy way would be to fire the submit via js with:

```
.submit();
```

The other way would be to disable validation on that form with this:

```
$('#form').validate({
   onsubmit : false
});
```

or

```
 $('#form').unbind('submit')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one suggestion. Name Add button inputs differently and add row using javascript/ajax. When posting, Add button inputs will not be validated because they have different names